# Select Distinct records from a Timestamp row using day only from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query only distinct dates from my table (ignoring the times) which uses timestamp for the date format (should I use a better format?).  Here is my query, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE(event_date)
    FROM schedule
    WHERE DATE(event_date) >= CURDATE()
    ORDER BY event_date ASC LIMIT 4
";
```

"event_date" is my timestamp row in the database.

Comment: How does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a problem with the `order by`.  How about this?

```
SELECT DATE(event_date)
FROM schedule
WHERE event_date >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(event_date)
ORDER BY DATE(event_date) ASC
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Hmm...still doesn't get any results for some reason.

Comment: @KeepCool . . . Does it return results if you use `WHERE DATE(event_date) >= CURDATE()`?

Comment: It gives results when I use "SELECT * " instead of "SELECT DATE(event_date)" It only shows 3 results, even though I have 5 unique dates in my table (as a test).

Comment: It worked. I'm not very smart...I I tried your solution the next day, which meant that yesterday's date wasn't showing..hence why I only had 3 results.